# Cloning windows from a hard disk drive to a m.2 ssd

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd, clone

I'm looking at cloning windows 8.1 which is on a hard drive onto a m.2 ssd. My understanding being the process would be installing the m.2 ssd, cloning the hard drive onto it. Then going into the bios and  setting the m.2 ssd as the boot drive. Is this correct? And will I have to pay for a new windows license key?

Comment: you understood it correct. You don't need a new license key.

Comment: You should make sure to use a cloning program properly as you can mess up all of your data. Program like ghost32, acronis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions in order of appearance:

1. Yes, your basic process is correct. You'll need to use specialized software like EaseUS Todo Backup to clone the drive partitions properly and avoid costly errors. [This post](http://lifehacker.com/5837543/how-to-migrate-to-a-solid-state-drive-without-reinstalling-windows) on Lifehacker has an excellent step-by-step tutorial on the whole process. I had to do this on my laptop as well, and this post was invaluable during the migration.
2. No, you will not need to purchase a new Windows license. Since you are not installing Windows on another computer, a new license isn't necessary.

Comment: Your post could use some expansion. A good [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) includes an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  For example, you could explain *why* a new license isn't required and *how you know that*.  Thanks for contributing to the community.

Comment: @Twisty Thanks for the tips. I've been a passive user for years and only just started answering questions today, so I'm new to this. I updated the post with appropriate improvements.

Comment: Excellent improvements to your answer. Upvoted accordingly. Glad to have your contributions. Good luck!

Comment: "Since you are ... a new license isn't necessary". IF and ONLY IF (a) the Windows license is a retail license; IOW, not an OEM license bound to the original hardware, OR (b) you are installing the M.2 drive to the original hardware.

Comment: Can we set m.2 ssd as the boot drive, and then clean install OS later using the key? (I don't know anything; I am asking the possibility)