# Transfer Bootable Windows 10 Partition to External Drive and then to Replacement Drive

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, external-hard-drive, clone, bootable-media

I have a Windows 10 installation on an internal M.2 drive that I need to transfer to another M.2 drive that will replace the older M.2 drive.

But I don't want to purchase additional hardware to convert an M.2 drive into an external drive so that I can transfer directly between the M.2 drives.

Instead I do have an external USB drive with an empty partition that can fit the M.2 drive's contents onto it.

So I presume there must be a way to copy the M.2 drive's contents onto the USB drive such that I can boot the cloned Windows 10 parition from the USB drive, and then do the process again with the new M.2 drive installed to transfer the bootable Windows 10 install from the bootable USB drive to the new M.2 drive.

The new M.2 drive has nothing on it and will need to be formatted before it can be used.

Comment: I would recommend a bootable disk cloning software like Acronis so that you can boot into it, make an exact copy of your original m.2, swap your m.2's and then boot into Acronis again and put the image of the first m.2 onto the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a variety of cloning tools, I found this to be the most efficient:

https://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm

As it allowed cloning of active disks which was required in my case.  However, since my SSD was formatted in exFAT, it was proving too difficult to shrink the partition to provide enough space for the cloned M.2.  In the end I decided to create a Windows install disk and put a fresh copy on the new M.2.

Thanks for your suggestions everyone!

Answer (score 0):

you can directly [clone m.2 disk to m.2 disk](http://www.backup-utility.com/clone/clone-m2-ssd-to-m2-ssd-5740i.html). to ensure the security of your data, the first thing is to make a backup for your disk. after you finish disk clone or only system clone, there are something you need to do.
1. use a screwdriver to take out your older m.2 disk and mount the new drive on the port where you take out your older m.2 disk
2. enter the BIOS to change boot sequence 
3. boot from your new m.2 disk
other things you need to know.
if your computers' boot mode is BIOS, you should use a MBR disk. if the mode is UEFI, you are supposed to boot from GPT disk. so ensure your boot mode and disk partition style. if you need to convert, here's a link for you: 
http://www.disk-partition.com/gpt-mbr/change-partition-style.html

Answer (score -1):

I would consider implementing the steps found here (twice): [Cloning windows from a hard disk drive to a m.2 ssd](https://superuser.com/questions/928251/cloning-windows-from-a-hard-disk-drive-to-a-m-2-ssd)

1. Make the proper back-ups.
2. Clone the original m.2 to the SSD.
3. Switch to booting from the SSD (in BIOS).
4. Clone the SSD to the new m.2.
5. Switch to booting from the new m.2 (in BIOS).